# std::optional::transform with std::addressof

Tags: c++, c++23, stdoptional

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
constexpr T * arg_to_pointer(T & arg) noexcept {
    return std::addressof(arg);
}

int main() {
    std::optional<int> foo;

    auto * test = foo.transform(arg_to_pointer<int>).value_or(nullptr);
    //auto * test = foo.transform(std::addressof<int>).value_or(nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The line that is not commented out (that passes a dumb wrapper around `std::addressof` as the function parameter to `std::optional::transform`) compiles and works just fine. The line that is commented out (the one that tries to use `std::addressof` directly) does not - I get an error indicating that template argument deduction failed (live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/shY9nYEYj) using GCC 13.2, though similar behavior is observed with Clang 16.0). Why is this? What is the difference between the standard `std::addressof` and my dumb wrapper around it?

Comment: [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) has overloads...

Comment: Does it though? That link says there is one version until C++17, and another since C++17. There is an explicitly deleted overload since C++17 as well - but it isn't clear to me why that should make a difference. I have explicitly copied the C++17 and on version for my function signature

Comment: If you add `template <typename T> constexpr T * arg_to_pointer(T&&) noexcept /*=delete*/;`, you would add similar issue.

Comment: Indeed you do - just tried that myself. So I guess my question is now: Why? Why does explicitly deleting an overload make something more ambiguous? Surely I have made it less ambiguous by telling you it can't be that overload?

Comment: Overload resolution is "independant" of the definition of such overload.

Comment: @RK - A deleted overload doesn't go away, but makes it an error if that overload is selected. So there are still two overloads, and `T=int` is not enough to tell them apart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) has overloads...

One for lvalue (since C++11), and one for rvalue (since C++17), so `std::addressof<int>` is ambiguous. (even if it would be surprising to take the deleted overload ;-) ).

Anyway, [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) is not a [addressable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction).

Comment: Had not realized the addressable function constraint. Thanks for that